# How to fix the Background Color to heading?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I was trying to add color to the heading but the design was horrible.
  I tryed to watch videos  on youtube but they dont help me with the position and the horizontal line bugs.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGG2E.jpg

I was expectating something like this
Paint model. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTBJH.jpg

But I'm very bad at positions

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lGG2E.jpg

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    h1 {
      text-align: left;
      color: #595959;
      background: #80ff80;
      width: 5000px;
      height: 60px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#ffb84d">
  <h1>Test</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Fixing the position,and  horizontal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove paddings and margins around the page, you can use:

```
html, body{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
```

To add a background color to body, you have to assign it in the styles ass well. You can select it with `body`:

```
body{
 background: #ffb84d;
}
```

If you further want a buttom border for the headline, you can add the following rules to h1:

```
h1 {
 text-align:left;
 color:#595959;
 background: #80ff80;
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 /* Specify a bottom border like this: */
 border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

Comment: The Style `text-align:left;`  and `width:100%;`  is default property of `<h1> `so in this case you no need to write them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `margin` of the `body` and of the `heading` to `0` to remove the border

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #ffb84d;
} 
h1 {
  margin: 0px;
  text-align:left;
  color:#595959;
  background-color: #80ff80;
 }
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <h1>Test</h1> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text-align:left;` is the default property here and `width:5000px;` will cause you a problem! It is creating an unnecessary horizontal  scrollbar, did you notice!